# can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column oracle

Tags: oracle

i'm probably missing something very obvious but i can't figure out what it is.

i'm getting an error "can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column".

below is the code i'm running. my table's field's datatype is VarChar2, not LONG. the variable i'm using to convert the blob is also declared as VarChar2, so what's LONG here?

i thought maybe the value i'm inserting is too long - but i'm posting the dbms output of what i'm trying to insert, it's on a line called FIELD.

thank you very much

here's the DBMS Output

LengthOfField 5

Field 1004t

and here's the code

```
    DROP TABLE ANALYST.NR_DTS_BLOBFIELDS_VARCHAR;

CREATE TABLE ANALYST.NR_DTS_BLOBFIELDS_VARCHAR(formid NUMBER
                            ,regionId VARCHAR(4000))
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
STORAGE(BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
     FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
     CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
NOMONITORING;






DECLARE
     CURSOR c_dts IS
       SELECT Form_ID
         FROM NR_DTS_FORMTABLE
        WHERE   1 = 1
           --AND ROWNUM BETWEEN 501 AND 4500
           AND form_ID > 204815
           --AND ROWNUM < 5000
           AND ROWNUM < 3
           --AND form_id IN (SELECT form_id FROM NR_DTS_BLOB)
           AND Form_Type_ID = 102;
     DTS c_dts%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     OPEN c_dts;
     LOOP
       FETCH c_dts INTO DTS;
       EXIT WHEN c_dts%NOTFOUND;
       DECLARE
         v_hold_blob BLOB;
         v_len NUMBER;
         v_raw_chunk RAW(10000);
         v_chr_string VARCHAR2(32767);
         -- v_chr_string CLOB;
         v_position NUMBER;
         c_chunk_len NUMBER := 1;
         Form_ID NUMBER;
       BEGIN
         SELECT form_content
           INTO v_hold_blob
           FROM NR_DTS_FORMTABLE
          WHERE Form_ID = DTS.Form_ID;
         v_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(v_hold_blob);
         v_position := 1;
         WHILE (v_position <= LEAST(v_len, 32767)) LOOP
              v_raw_chunk := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(v_hold_blob, c_chunk_len, v_position);
              v_chr_string := v_chr_string || CHR(hex_to_decimal(RAWTOHEX(v_raw_chunk)));
              v_position := v_position + c_chunk_len;
         END LOOP;

             DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(   'LengthOfField '
                     || INSTR((SUBSTR(v_chr_string, INSTR(v_chr_string, 'regionIdt') + LENGTH('regionIdt') + 2))
                          ,CHR(116)));
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(   'Field '
                     || SUBSTR(v_chr_string
                           ,INSTR(v_chr_string, 'regionIdt') + LENGTH('regionIdt') + 2
                           ,INSTR((SUBSTR(v_chr_string
                                   ,INSTR(v_chr_string, 'regionIdt') + LENGTH('regionIdt') + 2))
                              ,CHR(116) || CHR(0))));
       --insert into table
               INSERT INTO NR_DTS_BLOBFIELDS_VARCHAR(formid
                                                    ,regionId)
                    SELECT DTS.Form_ID
                          , SUBSTR(v_chr_string
                                             ,INSTR(v_chr_string, 'regionIdt') + LENGTH('regionIdt') + 2
                                             ,INSTR((SUBSTR(v_chr_string
                                                           ,INSTR(v_chr_string, 'regionIdt') + LENGTH('regionIdt') + 2))
                                                   ,CHR(116) || CHR(0)))
                                regionId
                      FROM DUAL;

           END;

       --  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DTS.Form_ID);
       END LOOP;
       CLOSE c_dts;
     END;
```

Comment: ok, i know why it's doing it but still don't know how to solve it. it's doing it because VarChar(32767) is long. but i'm inserting a small piece of it, so why can't i do it? i tried CAST and no luck

Answer (score 2):

i'm sorry, this was a stupid question. all i had to do was to create another variable and declare it as VarChar(under4000). and then set it to the value of the field i'm inserting.

i posted the answer in case anyone needs it but feel free to delete the question all together. i'm not sure what to do in cases like these (when i post and then figure it out later).

thank you :)